# use of venue's todo id

Tags: foursquare

When using [this service](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/listed), we receive an array called `listItems`, in which there are *TODO's* related to the venue.

These *todo's* have an id, but this ID cant be used for marking a *todo* as *done*. (for marking as *done* we use `tips/TIP_ID/markdone`).

I understand that the right ID for doing this is the tip ID. Is there anyway for relating the todo and tip ID's without having to call another service (as their relationship is one for one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to take the tip id (that is marked as "todo" for the user) and mark the tip as done with that same ID.

Have you tried using [/lists/additem](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/lists/additem.html), which is the now the preferred way to mark an item as done?